# Brezis's Functional Analysis Exercise 1.14 - Why is there no closed hyperplane separating $Y$ and $Z$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, hahn-banach-theorem

Consider Exercise 1.14 in Brezis' *Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations* below. My question regards item 3.. How to solve this? I am trying to show that there is no such hyperplane, by supposing that there is and arriving at a contradiction:

> Let $Z = X - c = \{x - c \ : \ x \in X\} = \{z \in \ell^1 \ : \ z_{2n} = -1/2^n \}$. Suppose there is $u \in Y \cap Z$. Then $y_{2n - 1} = -1$ for all $n \geq 1$ and therefore $y \notin \ell^1$, a contradiction. Hence $Y  \cap Z = \emptyset$.
>
> Suppose now that there is a closed hyperplane separating $Y$ and $Z$. Then there is some $f \in (\ell^1)^*$ such that
> $$
> f(y) \leq \alpha \leq f(z) \quad \forall y \in Y, z \in Z,
> $$
> where $[f = \alpha]$ is the hyperplane. Then there is $u \in \ell^\infty$ such that
> $$
> \sum_{n = 1}^\infty u_n y_n \leq \alpha \leq \sum_{n = 1}^\infty u_n z_n, \quad \forall y \in Y, z \in Z.
> $$
> But $Y$ is a subspace, so $f$ can only be bounded in $Y$ if $Y \subset \ker f$.

Here I am stuck. Any hints will be the most appreciated. Thanks in advance and kind regards.

[image]

Comment: $f(Y)$ is bounded above if and only if $Y \subseteq \ker f$. This doesn't tell you that $f$ vanishes everywhere. If it did, you would be done since the definition of a separating hyperplane requires $f \neq 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. You are right, I cannot assert that $f = 0$. How does one proceed, then?

Comment: You can use the other side of the inequality to prove that $f$ vanishes on $X$. Then use the first part of this exercise to see that $f=0$

Comment: @RhysSteele Here is what I got: 

Let $u \in \ell^\infty$ be such that 
$$
\sum_n u_n y_n = \sum_n y_{2n - 1}\left(u_{2n - 1} +  \frac{1}{2^n}u_{2n} \right) = 0 \quad \forall y \in Y.
$$
Then, taking in particular $y \in Y$ which has all entries zero except for $y_{2n - 1}$, we see that $u_{2n - 1} =  - \frac{1}{2^n}u_{2n}$. Then
$$
\sum_n u_n z_n = \sum_n -\frac{u_{2n}}{2^n} \left(z_{2n - 1} + 1\right).
$$

But I don't see how can we conclude that $f = 0$ in $X$, could you please develop a little more?

Comment: I think I got this, what is your opinion?

$$
\sum_n u_n z_n = \sum_n -\frac{u_{2n}}{2^n} (z_{2n - 1} + 1) = \sum_n u_{2n - 1} (x_{2n - 1} + 1) = \sum_n u_n x_n + \sum_n u_{2n - 1}.
$$
Therefore, $f$ is bounded from below on $X$, and hence we also have $X \subset \ker f$. By the first item, we conclude that $f = 0$, a contradiction. Hence there is no closed hyperplane separating $Y$ and $Z$.

Comment: This works as long as you write a brief argument as to why $\sum_n u_{2n-1}$ converges. Honestly introducing $u$ at all is just overcomplicating a simple problem though. If $x \in X$ then $x-c \in Z$ so that $f(x) = f(x-c) + f(c) \geq \alpha + f(c)$ so that $f$ is bounded below on $X$. This is much simpler since I don't have to use the fact that $f$ vanishes on $Y$ to see that $u$ has a particular form in order to get the last sum in your last comment to converge.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you very much for your help.